# SSRS Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) - date parameter format

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a report using the SSRS (visual studio 2017). The report has the date range parameters as @StartDate and @EndDate.

The date format from the data source is 'yyyy-mm-dd xx:xx:xx:xxx', and I would like the report's date parameters to be in 'yyyy-mm-dd' or one that you can select from the calendar.

Right now the report shows a calendar window and I can select a date, but the report does not display all the data under the entered date. For example, if I enter 10/01/2020 as the start date and the end date, the report does not return any data, although there is data that fall under the date.

Comment: You you only pass a date to your query rather than a date time, it will effectively append 00:00:00 to the end, so your query would only find anything with that exact date time. Try casting your database datetime to a date before comparing, e.g. WHERE CAST(myDateTimeField as date) = CAST(@pMyDateParameter as date)

Comment: What are you using for your query in the `WHERE` clause I would add `date BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate` if that is not what you are using already